# How to a allow a non-privileged user to show/hide cells in a protected range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet in which there are formulas and cells that I don't want users to be able to edit but would like to allow them to show/hide the rows and columns as they see fit. It appears that the protection mechanisms consider showing/hiding as editing whereas I do not.

Comment: Well, you can try to make a code for it. Check this [protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) part of the Apps Script documentation to check all the possible methods that you can use to achieve this kind of problem. You can also check the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) if this is achievable or not.

Comment: That seems like it could work....temporarily turning off cell protections for the duration of the script.

Comment: No go. The script runs in the non-privileged users context and it doesn't appear that a user can add themselves as an editor for a protected range which they are not a permitted editor.